# Search for multiple cities of unload

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

This is my table:

```
---------------------------------
| City of load | City of unload |
---------------------------------
| Enzesfeld    | Lublin         | 
---------------------------------
| Enzesfeld    | Tychy          |
---------------------------------
| Frankenmarkt | Uden           | 
---------------------------------
```

I want to find all cities of unload, where city of load is "Enzesfeld". Is there any formula that allows this?

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY(A1:B; "select B where A ='"&"Enzesfeld"&"'"; 1)
```

or

```
=QUERY(A1:B; "select B where A ='"&A2&"'"; 0)
```

or

```
=QUERY(A1:B; "select A, B where A ='"&"Enzesfeld"&"'"; 0)
```